# not all code path return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

error: not all code path returns a value,

i'm trying to return a dataset from function but getting this error,

code:

```
public partial class crystalReport_manual : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String conStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataSet1 ds = Dataset_load("Select * from login"); 

            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
            rd.SetDataSource(ds);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;



    }

    public DataSet1 Dataset_load(String query) 
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("select * from Login", sqlcon);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
       // DataSet ds = new DataSet("CRDataSet");

        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            //sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");

            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DT_CR");
            sqlDA.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            return ds;    
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Response.Write(exc.Message);
        }
        finally 
        {
            sqlcon.Close();
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DataSet1 Dataset_load(String query)
{
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    using(SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    using(SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("select * from Login", sqlcon))
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom))
    {
        try
        {
            //sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DT_CR");
            sqlDA.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            //return ds;

        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            Response.Write(se.Message);
            //return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Response.Write(exc.Message);
            //return null;
        }
    }

    return ds;

}
```

Building off the previous user's response, if an empty DataSet is returned at the end of your using statement, you can always check `ds.Tables.Count` to see if anything was returned. Otherwise you can use the logic above and `null` check

Comment: my previous code worked without any change, i just put RETURN NULL in Catch block and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

What if an exception occur, your `catch` or `finally` block should return some value.

Since you are only closing the connection in `finally` you can use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block like:

```
public DataSet1 Dataset_load(String query)
{
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    using(SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    using(SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("select * from Login", sqlcon))
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom))
    {
        try
        {
            //sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DT_CR");
            sqlDA.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            return ds;

        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            Response.Write(se.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Response.Write(exc.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`using` internally translates to `try-finally` block, and works with those which implements `IDisposable`, in `finally` block it calls the `Dispose` method, since `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataAdapter`, all implements `IDisposable` with `using` statement it will call `Dispose` at the end which would close the connection.

Comment: great but what if i just put return null; in catch block ? Using 'using' statements won't be necessary ? right ?

Comment: @Hunain, yes, the error will go away, but having `using` will save you from manually closing the connection. As a rule, if something implements `IDisposable` then always use using, other than Task :)

Comment: @Hunain, you are welcome, You should consider following the better coding practice, like `using` statement with `IDisposable`.